# pigeon hole sequence problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

**The prompt is to find the ways there are to sit n people on k chairs standing in a row so that no 2 people sit next to each other.**

Pigeon hole theorem is what I am using to attempt this problem.
since there are k chairs, and n people. we must have at least $k-n+1$ chairs.

Assuming people to be X and chairs to be O, it can be visualized as XOXOXOX so at least **n-1** unoccupied chairs are needed to occupy **n** people in a way that they aren't next to each other or vice versa.

So now we have $k-n+1$ holes and *n* pigeons to occupy these places, giving us ${k-n+1} \choose{n}$$n!$ ways to do this right since all people are unique.

Let's say we have 9 chairs and 4 people, we have $6\choose4$$4! = 450$ ways to do so.

Is this the correct way to approach a problem like this?